# Google cloud Error "The worker was unable to check in, possibly due to a misconfigured network"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nextflow

I'm trying to run the following nextflow pipeline on google cloud platform:

```
./nextflow run nf-core/sarek -profile test,gls -w gs://sustained-drake-299223-life-sciences
```

With nextflow.config file available at https://github.com/lescai/nf-gscloud/blob/main/sarek_gcp_example.config

Although nextflow is **successfully** set up according to an official [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/tutorials/nextflow#gsutil), this particular pipeline fails starting with a following warning, followed by an error:

```
WARN: Google Pipelines > A resource limit has delayed the operation: generic::resource_exhausted: allocating: selec
ting resources: selecting region and zone: no available zones: europe-west2: 510 DISKS_TOTAL_GB (16/4096 available)
 usage too high
```

```
 The worker was unable to check in, possibly due to a misconfigured network
```

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: The tutorial works fine for me. Usually this error is due to the selected zone/region `europe-west2` is currently unavailable due to high usage. Can you try using a different zone/region?